# is it impossible using find_element_by_xpath with fstring?

Tags: html, selenium

```py
test_ele_str='/html/body/form/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[4]'
test_ele=driver_p.find_element_by_xpath(test_ele_str)
```

```
var1=0
test_ele_str2=f'/html/body/form/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[{var1+1}]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[4]'
tem_ele=driver_p.find_element_by_xpath(test_ele_str2)
```

are they different?
when I run the first code, It goes well
but second, NoSuchElement Error happen 
what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

no it's not impossible.

try like this :

```
var1 = 1
test_ele_str2 = f'/html/body/form/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[{var1}]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[4]'
tem_ele = driver_p.find_element_by_xpath(test_ele_str2)
```